# Metodo 'includes()' estricto en JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy verificando con **JS** si en la ruta en la que me encuentro, incluye o no un estado, para activar una clase de CSS. Estos estados se recorren a través de un bucle, y lo verifico con:

```
window.location.href.includes(url.contains)
```

Este `url.contains` puede tener diferentes estados (valores), pero tengo dos estados que son: `provisional-final-allegation` y `final-allegation`.

Los cuales me están dando problemas por que se llaman casi igual, la diferencia es el `provisional-` que va al principio. Y el `includes()` me da como valido ambos, por lo que se me activan a la vez.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que el método `includes()` sea estricto y verifique exactamente lo que se le pasa por parámetro? ¿o algún otro método que pueda ayudarme?

Comment: Probaste a usar [String.endsWith(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)? Si no me equivoco existe también un `startsWith`... tal vez con esos te vaya mejor :)

Comment: El método `String.includes(substring)` te dice si un texto está incluido en otro. Si quieres algo estricto, entonces puedes usar simplemente `===`

Comment: [¿Y una expresión regular?](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado haciendo un `.split('/')` a la URL actual, para obtener un array con cada parte de la cadena. Ya que el estado venia en la URL de esta forma:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/des/developer/xxxxxxxx/public/xxxxxxx/provisional-final-allegation/index
```

Ahora de esta forma si verifica la el estado completo, sea cual sea:

```
let status_split = window.location.href.split("/");
status_split.includes(url.contains)
```

Gracias por la respuesta, y los comentarios.

Answer (score 3):

El comentario que te dejaron también está bien, pero si la parte que buscas no está en el inicio ni en el final del string no funcionará con `endsWith` ni `startsWith`.

Para hacer esto, necesitarás más que solo `includes`, puedes usar [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Puedes usar la siguiente expresión regular

```regex
/((provisional\-)?)final\-allegation/
```

Lo que hace es básicamente encontrar `provisional-final-allegation` y `final-allegation`, la parte principal es para decir que `provicional-` es opcional y que si está también la encuentre, pero si no está, que solo encuentre `final-allegation`.

De esta manera, puedes probarlo así

```js
console.log(location.href.match(/((provisional\-)?)final\-allegation/)[0]);
```

Como podrás ver, usamos corchetes de indexación, ya que [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) devuelve un array con las coincidencias que encontró la expresión, la salida será lo que encontró.

Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
const string = "/some/url/provisional-final-allegation/more/";
const string2 = "/some/url/final-allegation/more/";

console.log(
  string.match(/((provisional\-)?)final\-allegation/)[0],
  string2.match(/((provisional\-)?)final\-allegation/)[0]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

El método `String.includes(substring)` te dice si un texto está incluido en otro. Así que mi propuesta es no mirar en `window.location.href`, sino en otro campo de `window.location`:

Imaginemos que la URL que tenemos es

`https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/505444?pe=1&pa=hola#anchor`

- `window.location.pathname` es la parte de la URL que viene justo después del dominio/dirección IP, indicando el path del recurso, pero sin parámetros. En este caso sería:
  `"/questions/505444"`
- `window.location.search` es la parte con los *request params*: lo que viene tras el interrogante, pero sin incluir el *hash* (#): `?pe=1&pa=hola`
- `window.location.hash`: Como podrás imaginar, es en este caso `#anchor`

Así que podrías, por un lado, buscar sólo la parte que te interese y, por otro,

- usar una expresión regular con inicio y fin (`.match(/^...$/)`) o
- usar `split('/')` en el *path* (o `split('&')` en la parte *search*)  y mirar con `===' .